# Using Arrays or Dictionary for a drag and drop listbox

Tags: arrays, dictionary, listbox, mp3, filepath

Very new to this Visual Basic programming, but so far I'm really enjoying the experience.

I have a form that contains a listbox that has drag and drop abilites. I can drop the mp3 files on to the listbox and they just display the filename as I expected. I can double click the file in the listbox and it plays the music track and I can also delete the track in the listbox.

My querie is, how do I create an array to store the file path's and the filename's or should I use the dictionary method to store both items. The list box can contain upto 80 mp3 filenames and this also has to be saved to a file. Which I managed to do.

What I have at the moment works, but not well. Does the dictionary method auto update as new files are added to the list. The SelectedTrackLocation and SelectedTrackTitle are the variables that I am using.

Things go wrong when I have multiple Items in the listbox from 2 or more folders. How do I go about solving this?

```
    Dim thefilesPath() As String = CType(e.Data.GetData("FileDrop", True), String())
    For Each theFileName As String In thefilesPath
        Dim directoryPath As String = Path.GetFullPath(theFileName)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(theFileName))
        SelectedTrackLocation = directoryPath
        SelectedTrackTitle = theFileName
        'MsgBox("File Path = ..." & directoryPath)
    Next
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get the Dictionary working as I need. This was all I needed to do... Dictionary.Add(songtitle, songsdirectoryPath)